# Which nesting structure (BEM) to use, without modifying the HTML

Tags: css, sass

I have two JS components, Parent and Child, each one with its own scss stylesheet. Parent pass a modifier string to Child: `one` or `two`. Child renders this modifier in its main `div` as a BEM modifier class:

```
    <div className="parent">
        <div className="parent__title">This is parent</div>
        <div className="child child--one">
            <div className="child__title">Hello, this is one</div>
            <ul className="child__list">
                <li className="child__item">item1</li>
                <li className="child__item">item2</li>
                <li className="child__item">item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="child child--two">
            <div className="child__title">Hello, this is two</div>
            <ul className="child__list">
                <li className="child__item">item1</li>
                <li className="child__item">item2</li>
                <li className="child__item">item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want Child to be unaware of Parent, so I can not modify its style in Child.scss: has to be done in Parent.scss.

This is Parent.scss:

```
    .parent {
      $root: &;

      .child--one {
        color: tomato;

        &__item {
          color: yellow;
        }
      }

      .child--two {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
```

Here the `color: yellow;` rule is not applied to `.parent .child--one child__item`, because it is targeting `.parent .child--one__item`.

The question is:

**without modifying the HTML structure, how can I manage to target `.parent .child--one .child__item` in an elegant and simple way?**

I would like, if possible, to maintain `.child` nested inside `.parent` in the stylesheet, to avoid polluting the stylesheets.

Comment: Hi Nikita, I proposed an editing in your question to make it more specific so it can be more accessible to others. I also wrote an answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: You're welcome @Nikita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think this is the most organized way to write what you propose.

```
.parent {
  $root: &;

  .child--one {
    color: tomato;
    .child {
        &__item {
          color: yellow;
        }
    }
  }

  .child--two {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

*Note that `yellow` only affects `.child--one` items and you got to repeat `.child` inside `.child--one` in order to reuse the BEM benefits according to your classes names. For example, if you later wanna style `&__title` or `&__list`*

- On the other hand, if you want to reuse `.child__item` regardless in which child it is, you can do this:

```
.parent {
    $root: &;

    .child {
        &--one {
            color: tomato;
        }
        &--two {
            color: blue;
        }
        &__item {
            color: yellow;
        }
    }
}
```